# splash screen not showing up - Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, screen, nine-patch, splash-screen

I have an 9 patch image named 'default.9.png' that I need to use in my app. I have put the png file in the directory /assets/android and deleted the old 'default.png', but the old splash screen continues to show up. I have tried deleting my /build folder and placing the image directly in the Resources/android directory, but still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the root directory (under your project name), create the following directory structure: platform/android/res. Inside the 'res' folder, create directories such as 'drawable-mdpi' and 'drawable-hdpi', etc. for all of the different resolutions you need. Then, in each of those directories, add your 9 patch splashscreen, naming it 'background.9.png'.